# Initializing a NotificationController in DNN 7

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-6, dotnetnuke-7

How do you initialize a `NotificationController` in DNN 7.1.2?

I've tried:

```
var nc = new DotNetNuke.Services.Social.Notifications.NotificationController();
```

However this is empty and has no methods to call... Am I initializing the wrong thing?

Surely there should be something in there other than `ToString`, `GetType`, `Equals` and `GetHashCode`

I need to be able to create NotificationTypes and create Notifications.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `NotificationsController.Instance.SendNotification` method to send notifications. 
Here is the example:

```
var notificationType = NotificationsController.Instance.GetNotificationType("HtmlNotification");
var portalSettings = PortalController.GetCurrentPortalSettings();
var sender = UserController.GetUserById(portalSettings.PortalId, portalSettings.AdministratorId);

var notification = new Notification {NotificationTypeID = notificationType.NotificationTypeId, Subject = subject, Body = body, IncludeDismissAction = true, SenderUserID = sender.UserID};
NotificationsController.Instance.SendNotification(notification, portalSettings.PortalId, null, new List<UserInfo> { user });
```

This will send notification to a specific user.

Comment: `NotificationsController` uses DNN's (kind of weird) `ServiceLocator` pattern, where it's just a static container which gives you an instance of an interface when you call the static `Instance` method.  It's mainly there to support testability; there's a static `SetTestableInstance` method you can call if to get an alternate instance in your tests.  There are a lot of types that follow this pattern throughout DNN (and many of the older controllers which don't follow the pattern have a `Testable*Controller` counterpart which does).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to create your own Notification type use the code below as a guide, it will create a NotificationType "GroupApprovedNotification".  This is from core groups module.

```
type = new NotificationType { Name = "GroupApprovedNotification", Description = "Group Approved Notification", DesktopModuleId = deskModuleId };
if (NotificationsController.Instance.GetNotificationType(type.Name) == null)
{
    NotificationsController.Instance.CreateNotificationType(type);

}
```